# Начинает тормозить Android Studio когда начинаю код в xml

Tags: android-studio, xml

У меня начинает Android Studio тормозить когда я начинаю что-либо писать в xml, Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Если да, пожалуйста прошу помочь(не могу выполнить таску)